# Ubuntu 20.10 installer not seeing existing Windows 10 installation

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, 20.10

I tried installing Ubuntu 20.10 and created a USB drive using the latest available .iso for 20.10.

I already had Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10 (2 separate windows 10 installations on different drives).

Upon restarting and going through the installation process, while in 20.04 I was told about the existing Windows installation and being asked to install along existing installations, in this new version 20.10, it shows there are no other existing installations.

I went with manual disk layout and ended up with broken grub so I could not boot into Windows or Ubuntu.

After spending 2 days trying all possible combinations, the solution was to burn version 20.04 into the USB flash and to reinstall ubuntu. This time the installer detected windows 10 and was able to install and correct the grub startup menu.

Is there a bug about this?

Comment: Did you always install in UEFI boot mode?

Comment: @oldfred - My PC can only run in non-UEFI because if I set it to UEFI, the graphics card misbehaves (Nvidia Quadro 2000). So BIOS setting is in Legacy mode - meaning non-UEFI.

Comment: Do not know of any specific bug for BIOS installs. Did you select the drive, not a partition for install of grub2 boot loader the first time?

Comment: @oldfred, I guess there is a specific bug about UEFI. About where I installed grub2 the first time - it was on drive C:. Actually when I installed ubuntu the first time, it detected windows automatically and set up grub on drive C:. Not sure whether it was drive or partition though. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You never ever install grub to a NTFS partition only to a drive. NTFS has vital info in the PBR - partition boot sector. If grub is installed to a NTFS partition you have to recovery the backup NTFS boot sector.

Comment: @oldfred you are right. I had to recover the partition from Windows - using BCDBoot, but even after doing that, 20.10 installer was not able to detect windows 10. Only switching to 20.04 installer helped - by detecting windows immediately

Comment: Bit surprised one worked but not other. Both in UEFI mode as sometimes different drivers are loaded?. And did Windows do an update in-between? Windows likes to turn fast start up back on with updates. That sets hibernation flag preventing Linux NTFS driver from seeing Windows. Or UEFI update which with many systems Windows does  changes settings back to defaults?